# How to set environment variable into docker container using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to set credentials to use Google Translate Api Client so I have to set environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` that value is path to credential file (from Google Cloud).

When I have been used `docker build` and `docker run` it was pretty easy.

I have been used `docker run
--env GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/usr/src/app/CryptoTraderBot-901d31d199ce.json` and environment variable has been set.

More difficult things come when I tried to set it in docker-compose. I have to use docker-compose because I need few containers so it is only way to achieve this.

Based on [Docker compose environment variables documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) I created my docker-compose.yml file that looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
redis:
  image: redis:4-alpine
crypto-bot:
  build: .
  depends_on:
    - redis
  environment:
    - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = /usr/src/app/CryptoTraderBot-901d31d199ce.json
```

I also have been tried multiple combination of path to .json file but none of this has been worked properly.

Have you got any idea how can I set it properly ?

Answer (score 10):

While creating this question I have been resolve this problem in a funny and easy way but I have been thought that I post answer to help someone in the future with similiar problem.

All you have to do is remove " " (space) next `=` sign so two last lines of docker-compose.yml should looks like this: 

`environment:
  - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/usr/src/app/CryptoTraderBot-901d31d199ce.json`

Comment: Man, you are rock! I have been searching for my problem for 2 hours.

Answer (score 3):

Docker Compose has a newer feature called secrets. You can bind the credentials like this:

```
services:
  secret-service:
      build:
        context: secret-service
      environment:
        - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/run/secrets/gcp-credentials
      secrets:
        - gcp-credentials

secrets:
  gcp-credentials:
    file: ./gcp-credentials.json
```

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#secrets

Comment: On Ubuntu, you may use this: `file: $HOME/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json` under secrets:gcp-credentials