# Docker-compose - setting environment variables that are not literals

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have setup Jenkins within a Docker container and I am trying to access that my private Bitbucket repo with that server. I need to copy my SSH key into that container so that Bitbucket recognizes it and I can have my Jenkins server access the repo then.

I have in my docker-compose.yml file the following:

```
services:
  jenkins:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
    environment:
      - SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"

volumes:
  jenkins-data:
```

However, `echo $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` gives `/.ssh/id_rsa` literally instead of the value stored inside. I have heard the problem with doing this inside the Dockerfile instead would be that it still can be viewed in one of the layers of the image that will be pushed.

My question is how can I set the value of `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` to the value of the contents of my file?

I believe this could be a duplicate of [How to set environment variable into docker container using docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50238621/how-to-set-environment-variable-into-docker-container-using-docker-compose) however that solution does not appear to change anything for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create an Environment variable in your shell from which you are running your compose :

```
export SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

and then use it in your compose like :

```
services:
  jenkins:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
    environment:
      - SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
```

It should pick up the value for your environment variable for container from shell environment as specified in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#pass-environment-variables-to-containers) :

> The value of the variable in the container is taken from the value for the same variable in the shell in which Compose is run.

Comment: I wander how to use this SSH_PRIVATE_KEY value in the container as a private key?

Comment: @Adiii using the jenkins [Configuration as Code Plugin](https://jenkins.io/projects/jcasc/) taking the private key from the container environment.

Comment: Ah thanks @michalk I just tested it and that works! However I now realize that what I had in mind isn't going to work as I need it during build time of the image whereas currently the value is only being assigned afterwards. I am going to try to pass it in as a build arg and see if that will work for me

Comment: @Adiii I wasn't using that plugin as a container, I was trying to create a multi stage build in my Dockerfile, as I was afraid I could leak the SSH key otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
    environment:
      - SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
```

and call the docker-compose like this:

```sh
SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa) docker-compose build
```

Unfortunately, it's currently not possible to use multiline variables in `.env`.

Another possibility would be:

```
services:
  jenkins:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
      - "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa:/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa:ro"      
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"

volumes:
  jenkins-data:
```

Comment: It should work however you can ommit the `${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}` as docker-compose can pick the values from the local env with the same name (as shown in my answer). Anyway +1.

Comment: true, I always put it there since I often use different variable names and default values depending on the image. I remove it in this case