# use ssh keyfile as environment variable in docker-compose

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-plugins, ssh-keys

I've run into the problem that I need to get a ssh keyfile as environment variable within my docker container.

My thing is, that I don't want to include the value hardcoded at build time of the container but at runtime as environment variable.

*My tl;dr question is:*

**Is there any way to assign the contents of a file (in my case a ssh key) to an environment variable in docker-compose?**

I'd imagine something like this:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  jenkinspink:
    image: jenkinspink:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

    # Here I want to pass a ssh keyfile as environment variable to the docker container
    environment:
      EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=<ssh_keyfile_on_host_system>
```

In my specific use case I need the ssh key to configure the EC2-Plugin in Jenkins. I'm doing this via JCasC (Jenkins Configuration as Code). Neither the EC2-Plugin nor the JCasC configuration allow the usage of a file path for the ssh key. Both want it as environment variable.
Now I see only 2 options:

- Either I do it the clean way by forking the EC2-Plugin repository and adapt the *ssh key* section in a way that allows file paths to be injected and then do a pull request.
- Or I do the quick way my question refers to by injecting the file via docker-compose as environment variable. But I don't know how.

Any hints appreciated :-D

Comment: You can pass the contents of the keys from the hosts environment to the containers environment, e.g. in your `docker-compose.yml`: `EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=${EC2_PRIVATE_KEY}` then set `EC2_PRIVATE_KEY` on the host when bringing up the environment i.e.: `EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa) docker-compose up -d`.

Comment: The way this kind of thing is done in kubernetes secrets is by base64 encoding it. That will probably work here, too, but since you need to create the key file inside the container anyway, why not just copy one in through the Dockerfile at build time?

Comment: @masseyb yeah. I guess I could go with that. Looks legit :-D I'll try!

Comment: @Dov Rine That's the point. The EC2-Plugin as well as the JCasC plugin don't accept files as input. They want the value within an environment variable. But thanks anyways

Comment: this question is really similiar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58622131/docker-compose-setting-environment-variables-that-are-not-literals) one - what a coincidence it was asked several hours ago.